# How to zip large files in s3 and then download it

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

greetings, I use this medium because I currently have a problem: I need to download files from s3 through a lambda function, all compressed in a .zip file.

The code I show below works when the generated file weighs a maximum of 5GB, recently I tried to download 60 assets of 500MB each and the generated file only had 7 correct files, the other files are shown as damaged files.

The algorithm does its job, but I think the fact that as they are stream files the lambda runs out of memory also influences, and what comes to mind is to divide everything into parts and chunks, but so far I have not found something that works for me, has this happened to someone? Please help

```
const archiver = require('archiver');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const stream = require('stream');
const REGION = debug ? 'myRegion' : process.env.REGION;
const FOLDER_LOCATION = debug ? 'myDownloads' : process.env.FOLDER_LOCATION;
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01', region: REGION });
const { API_DEV, API_QA, API_PRO } = require('./constants');
let isSocketConencted = false;
let socket;

const main = async (uuid, asset, nameZip, client, arrayObjects, channel, env) => {
  const api = env === 'dev'
    ? API_DEV
    : env === 'qa'
      ? API_QA
      : API_PRO;

  socket = io(api, { path: '/sockets' });
  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('socket conectado');
    isSocketConencted = true;
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('socket desconectado');
    isSocketConencted = false;
  });

  const bkt = env === 'dev'
    ? 'bunkey-develop'
    : env === 'qa'
      ? 'bunkey-qa'
      : 'bunkey-prod';

  const s3DownloadStreams = arrayObjects.map(o => {
    const [folder, fullName] = o.url.split('/').slice(o.url.split('/').length - 2);
    const fileName = fullName.split('.')[0];
    const ext = fullName.split('.')[1];
    return {
      stream: s3.getObject({ Bucket: bkt, Key: `${folder}/${fileName}.${ext}` }).createReadStream(),
      filename: `${o.name}.${ext}`,
    };
  });

  const streamPassThrough = new stream.PassThrough();
  const params = {
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Body: streamPassThrough,
    Bucket: bkt,
    ContentType: 'application/zip',
    Key: `${FOLDER_LOCATION}/${nameZip.replace(/\//g, '-')}.zip`,
    StorageClass: 'STANDARD_IA',
  };

  const s3Upload = s3.upload(params, error => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Got error creating stream to s3 ${error.name} ${error.message} ${error.stack}`);
      throw error;
    }
  });

  const archive = archiver('zip', {
    gzip: true,
    zlib: {
      level: 9,
    }
  });

  archive.on('error', error => {
    throw new Error(`${error.name} ${error.code} ${error.message} ${error.path} ${error.stack}`);
  });

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3Upload.on('close', resolve);
    s3Upload.on('end', resolve);
    s3Upload.on('error', reject);

    archive.pipe(streamPassThrough);
    s3DownloadStreams.forEach(streamDetails => archive.append(streamDetails.stream, { name: streamDetails.filename }));

    archive.finalize();
  }).catch(async error => {
    await handleSocketEmit(env, { uuid, channel, status: 'error', message: error.message });
    throw new Error(`${error.message}`);
  });

  const result = await s3Upload.promise();
  if (result && result.Location) {
    await handleSocketEmit(env, { uuid, asset, status: 'success', client, nameZip, channel, url: result.Location });
    await handleSocketDestroy();
    return { statusCode: 200, body: result.Location };
  } else {
    await handleSocketEmit(env, { uuid, channel, status: 'error' });
    await handleSocketDestroy();
    return { statusCode: 500 };
  }
};

const handleSocketDestroy = async () => {
  socket.close();
  socket.destroy();
};

const handleSocketEmit = async (env, msg) => {
  try {
    if (isSocketConencted) {
      socket.emit('request_lambda_download', msg);
    } else {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        await handleSocketEmit(env, msg);
      }, 1000);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('handleSocketEmit.err: ', error);
  }
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { uuid, asset, nameZip, client, arrayObjects, channel, env } = event;
  const result = await main(uuid, asset, nameZip, client, arrayObjects, channel, env);
  return result;
};
```

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you have multiple (unzipped) objects in Amazon S3 and you would like the Lambda function to convert them into a Zip file and put that Zip file back into S3? How often are you needing to do this? Have you tried temporarily changing the Lambda function to have maximum memory to see if it works? Have you considered doing it from an Amazon EC2 instance instead? Why are you wanting to do this in a Lambda function?

Comment: (1) Hello @JohnRotenstein thanks for answering this question, and yes! I have several objects decompressed in S3, I want to compress them all into a single file and make it available in another location in the same bucket and then send the download link to my api and then to the client, and in this way later download it.

This functionality can be used frequently, possibly every day there are people who download assets in my app.

Can you explain a little more how it is to temporarily change the LAMBDA function? I currently have the memory set to the maximum in the configuration ...

Comment: (2) ... of the function for this process.

I have little experience with aws and would have to investigate how it would be worth trying from EC2.

The idea of doing it with a lambda function arises by freeing the api of this load, and initially the behavior was very good, but after many large files it began to fail.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your requirements is to download uncompressed objects from Amazon S3, create a zip and then upload the zip back to Amazon S3.

Your problems appear to be stemming from the fact that the Lambda function is streaming content and manipulating it in memory, rather than disk. AWS Lambda functions only have 512MB of disk space allocated, which can make it difficult to manipulate potentially large files.

If you wish to keep using AWS Lambda to do this work, then I would recommend:

- Create an [Amazon EFS filesystem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html)
- [Attach the EFS filesystem](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/) to the Lambda function
- Modify your Lambda function to **download all files to EFS**
- The Lambda function can then **create a zip of the local files** and upload it to Amazon S3

This avoids all the streaming and memory requirements. It can actually run with much lower (minimum?) memory settings, which means the Lambda function runs at a much lower cost.

Comment: Thanks for your support friend, I am following your recommendations.!

Comment: Lambda now supports up to 10,240MB ephemeral storage. If you are certain that the total size of your files will be less than that, then you can reduce complexity by just using the temporary Lambda storage. The FAQ does briefly compare EFS, S3, and Lambda storage - https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/